# Connect NodeJS as client to third party service that uses session data

Tags: node.js, rest, session, authentication

I am developing a website in Node.JS / Express, and have until now used JWTs to store authentication data.

To summarize, I have an AngularJS app which calls a REST service on Node, and for authentication the user POSTs username and data to the server and gets a JWT containing the username and expiration, which then gets sent along with every request which requires authentication.

Now, though, I need to be able to connect to a third party service (which is a REST service that runs on Delphi) which uses sessions to save authentication data instead.

Using Fiddler, I can see that the service, when used in another implementation (third party) responds with JSON authentication data. In all subsequent requests, the client sends a cookie called *dsessionid*, although it doesn't appear in the "response cookies" in the previous response.

My question is: how do I take that dsessionid cookie in my NodeJS app and put it in my JWT so I can send it to my actual client?

Comment: Dude I lost you in the end. Can you just directly point out what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I'm trying to understand how I can read that "dsessionid" cookie the moment it gets set, which is when I send login data to the Delphi service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by getting the session ID in the "Pragma" header of the response (I don't know if the header is something "default" for Delphi applications or if it was specific to this application, I had to look through Fiddler entries to find out what header had the data) and then using a custom cookie jar with the [request module](https://github.com/request/request) to put the session ID in the cookies of subsequent requests.

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')

return request.get({   
  url: 'http://example.com:20202/auth',
  resolveWithFullResponse: true
}) 
.then(res => {
  return res.headers['pragma']
})
.then(sid => {
  let j = request.jar()
  j.setCookie(request.cookie('sessionid=' + sid), 'http://example.com')

  return request.get({
    url:'http://example.com:20202/fetchData',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    jar: j
})
```

Hope this helps somebody.